# How to get both REPL/arrow key functionality and Unicode characters working with Python3 under Git Bash/WinPTY

Tags: python, windows, unicode, windows-console, git-for-windows

Windows 7, restricted user account running
Git `git version 2.14.1.windows.1`

MINGW/MSYS `MINGW64_NT-6.1 REDACTED 2.8.2(0.313/5/3) 2017-07-12 15:35 x86_64 Msys`

Python `Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 24 2015, 22:44:40) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32`

locale has been set:

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Python IO Encoding env variable has been set

```
$ env | grep "PYTHON"
PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8
```

Now for the 'tests':

```
$ /c/Python34/python.exe -i
Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 24 2015, 22:44:40) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdout.encoding
'utf-8'
>>> print('\u2660')
♠
>>>
```

Unicode works but the arrow key functionality has been lost in the REPL.  So instead, execute using WinPTY

```
$ winpty /c/Python34/python.exe -i
Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 24 2015, 22:44:40) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdout.encoding
'utf-8'
>>> print('\u2660')
ΓÖá
>>>
```

Now I can navigate the history in the REPL, but Unicode is wonky.

So seemingly I can either be able to use the arrow keys in the REPL or proper unicode encoding, but not both.  Anyone else have this issue or did I miss something here that will make this all work?

**Note:** I am restricted to this environment; I cannot readily install/update/modify apps at will.

Comment: In the `WinPTY` case, the console is still using `cp437` (default US OEM Windows encoding) but you've force Python to output UTF-8 via `PYTHONIOENCODING`.  Can you update to Python 3.6?  That version now uses the Windows Unicode console APIs to output Unicode and shouldn't have issues.

Comment: So mintty creates a hidden console that bash inherits uselessly, and the standard handles are instead set to named pipes, which Python inherits, so we're forced to use `-i` and `PYTHONIOENCODING` to get around Python's default behavior when standard I/O is piped. Then of course Python no longer has the console's cooked read for input history and input editing. So we'll solve that with winpty and winpty-agent, which creates another hidden console for Python and depends on dubious polling of the screen buffer. Too convoluted. I'll stick to running MSYS bash as a normal console application.

Comment: @Mark Tolonen: Thanks! I tested on another unrelated machine, first matching my current environment, then installed Python 3.6.2, which I was't aware was available in my environment, and yes, that worked!

Comment: Cool, I'll make the comment an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the WinPTY case, the console is still using cp437 (default US OEM Windows encoding) but you've force Python to output UTF-8 via PYTHONIOENCODING. Switch to Python 3.6 since that version now uses the Windows Unicode console APIs to output Unicode and shouldn't have issues with encodings.